# Python PyQt5 Open Window maximized (Fullscreen) in MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, qt, pyqt5, qt5

I'm developing a simple paint app with Python and PyQt5. The app runs perfectly on Windows as well as on macOS. But the only problem is that I need the app to run in fullscreen mode. I'm using the following code snippet for that

```
screen = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
self.setGeometry(0, 0, screen.width(), screen.height())
self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

It works perfectly for windows and runs in fullscreen mode. But in macOS, the top bar (Menu bar) and the bottom app dock stay visible. Take a look at the screenshot attached below.
How can I solve this?
[image]

Comment: Does [showFullScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#showFullScreen-method) or [showMaximized](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#showMaximized-method) from the docs help at all?

Comment: I added self.showFullScreen() and it crashed the program without giving any error

Comment: Try using those methods instead of `.show()` when you display the window